# Windows gcloud init

Tags: windows, init, gcloud

There is a problem.

error occurs when you run the gcloud init command.

```
[C:\Users\xxxxx\default]:C:\gcloud.repo
Cloning into 'C:\gcloud.repo'...
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your OAuth token password; Note that generated google.com passwords are not compatible with private repositories
[source repos clone default C:\gcloud.repo] has failed
You can use [gcloud config] to change more gcloud settings.

Your current configuration is: [default]

[compute]
region = xxxxxxxxxx
zone = xxxxxxxxxx
[core]
account = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[meta]
active_config = default
ERROR: (gcloud.init) Failed command: [source repos clone default C:\gcloud.repo] with exit code [1]
```

OS: Windows 10

Someone, or you do not know the solution?

Comment: Do you have Git installed and on your path?

Comment: Are you using Cygwin by any chance? Also, note that the `gclout init` command was mostly successful. It's just the last part that failed. If you'd like to attempt to clone this repository again, you may run `gcloud source repos clone default C:\gcloud.repo`.